# Sitecore html encoded characters

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I have a title field of single-line text and noticing Editors often use the & symbol, this then renders and doesn't meet validation as it needs to be html value `&amp;`.

What is the process to obtain encoded characters from Sitecore without using Microsoft AntiXss Library which is not available in this project.

Example code using HTML Encode as part of a concat

```
string title = item["Title"] // returns a string: Terms & Conditions
url2use = "<li><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal-" + i + "'>";
url2use += HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(title);
url2use += "</a></li>";
```

I was expecting HTML Encode to convert the & to correct HTML equivalent

Comment: Can you please provide the code you are using to render the title?

Comment: Hi, have amended original question to include current code

Comment: Is the url2use variable of type string?

Answer (score 0):

Please patch the following setting:

```
<setting name="Rendering.HtmlEncodedFieldTypes" value="text|single-line text"/>
```

Remove the `|single-line text` and try not to use the `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()` to see if the `&` is rendering properly.